# Action on UIAlertController that does not dismiss AlertController? (Disable dismissing)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewanimationtransition, uialertcontroller

I have an action sheet (`UIAlertController` with style of `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`) with a few actions, presented on an iPad as a popover. What I want is, when a user selects one of the options (say, the first one), I want the action sheet to transition to a different action sheet, using the "Show" (previously "Push") animation. Is this possible? Or, if this is not possible, is it possible to present the second action sheet as a popover from the action tapped (I'd prefer the transition method, if possible).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply call your second alert from the action of the first and present it with a custom animation object however you want.

Comment: @Nikita When you tap on an action it dismisses the AlertController.

I'm not sure how to do that, anyway.

Comment: There is no way to prevent the alert controller from dismissing. That's one big change (and limitation) from the older `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: Is is possible to disable the action (without making it look disabled) and add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to it?

Comment: No. Sounds like you need to write your own similar control or find one that does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nice thing about iOS 7 and 8 in this regard is that it really is quite easy to write a view controller that looks and acts like an alert - except that it's just a view controller, so you can put any content you like into it and you can make it behave however you want.

For an example, see this github project of mine: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

As you'll see, all we're doing is starting with a small view designed in a *.xib* file and controlled by a view controller. Then we present the view controller. This view controller knows how to animate the appearance of the view and put a "dimmer" view behind it, just like an alert! And indeed this is not surprising, because in iOS 8 an alert controller *is* a presented view controller, so there's no reason why you shouldn't imitate its behavior. It isn't doing anything you can't do yourself.

Comment: It's unfortunate that there's nothing better.

Comment: I don't agree. I think that at this point this is exactly what you're expected to do. Apple has demoted the built-in alerts and promoted customizable presented view controllers.

Comment: It is great that Apple has "promoted customizable presented view controllers", but I agree with @ricky3350 that it is unfortunate to have to create a custom view controller that looks identical to Apple's just to gain this little bit of custom functionality.

Comment: @RichardVenable I secretly see your point of view also, but I'm not willing to say so in public. (Ooops, did I say that out loud?)